# does constructor allow to bind undefined method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am studying react and following the guide: event handling section, and watching binding of an event handler to a class in a constructor.
There's a thing I want to understand.
Why is it's okay to bind yet **undefined** method of a class in the `constructor`? or are methods of a class initialized before the `constructor`? or algoritm of class intialization starts with the constructor but it's possible to define already binded function later?

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
...
```

Comment: `console.log(this.handleClick)` in your constructor and you'll come to the conclusion that answers this question. Also, usually you only use that binding at the moment you register the callback: (`element.addEventListener('event', func.bind(this))`)

Comment: console.log(this.handleClick) shows me a function when the method is defined, and displays an error (Cannot read properties of undefined) when it's not. I asked this stupid question because javascript interpretes code line by line (as I was told) but in this case it binds undefined function, that confuses me. I know it might be a brain lag, but I still don't understand it.

Comment: Did you actually __try__ the `console.log`? What did it show you? I'm trying to get you to realize where your misconception lies.

Comment: Also, JavaScript doesn't just blindly run the code line by line. If that were the case, classes couldn't work.

Comment: Yes I tried console.log. 
I entered it right after render() and before return. 
It showed me 3 times this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind') and one more The above error occurred in the <App> component:

    at App (http://localhost:3000/main.728f6545b772adef6cb5.hot-update.js:27:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

Comment: As I said, _"in your constructor"_

Comment: Sorry, I misread. But even when I put it inside the constructor it still gives me the same errors.
this is how my code looks like: 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLoginClick = this.handleLoginClick.bind(this);
    console.log(this.handleLoginClick)
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>{this.handleLoginClick()}</div>
    );
  }

Comment: Impossible. If your function definition is as you have in in your question, then the function reference is available in your constructor. A class gets parsed, all function definitions get, well, defined, and then the constructor runs.

Comment: so  do you mean the constructor runs last?

Comment: @George No. The constructors runs when you call it with `new`. As long as that is after the `class` was defined, the whole class - including all prototype methods - has been defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function definitions in classes are initialized before the constructor runs. Here's an example:

```js
class Bar {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log('Bar constructor');
    console.log(props);
  }
}

class Foo extends Bar {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('Foo constructor');
    console.log(this.handleClick);
    
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

const foo = new Foo({a: 1});

console.log('`this` in handleClick:');
foo.handleClick();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: thanks! I understand now. though I asked plain text `are methods of a class initialized before the constructor` and you could just answer "yes":)
My bad that I didn't find out it by myself

Comment: I always try to help people find the answer by themselves, first. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: sure, you are right with your approach. Next time I'll be more patient and smart and console.log everything and anywhere before asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it's okay to bind yet undefined method of a class in the constructor? or are methods of a class initialized before the constructor?

kind of, and not exactly. The point is JS' prototype based inheritance.

You create your `class Foo {}`. At that point the methods are defined on the class' `prototype` "long" before you even thought of calling `new Foo()`. When you then instantiate the class there are basically 3 things happening behind the scenes:

```
const instance = Object.create(null);
```

1. JS allocates the memory and creates a new (basically empty) object.

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(instance, Foo.prototype);
```

2. Then it attaches the prototype from the class and turns this object into an instance of the class.

   But unlike other languages it does not actually write the methods onto the object, they are only available through the prototype chain. 
    **that's why I wrote "not exactly"*

```
Foo.call(instance, ...args);
```

3. Calling the constructor on the instance. *This code-snippet is technically not correct, but representative.*

That's why the method is already defined in the constructor. Through the prototype chain, the instance can access the method defined on the class' prototype object.

When you now do `this.method = this.method.bind(this);` you access the `Foo.prototype.method`, because the instance has no own property with that name, then you create a new function that is bound to `this` (the instance) and write that new bound function onto the instance. 
And from that point on `this.method` will access the bound function on the instance and no longer the "original" method from the prototype.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
That's the kind of answer I was hoping exactly when posted my silly question, which I could solve just logging but for some reason I thought It's illegal to log in the constructor, like it is only for properties for an object.

now it's clear why the method was already defined.